# Disable REST URI calls

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I am developing a project which can disable a particular REST URI at runtime so that consumers will get an error. I have created interface/controller for disabling a URI. But I can not figure out how to disable it.

I thought of setting disable flag for the URI and sending blank data, but consumer needs to see an error.

I can not use Response every where.

Need Help

Comment: share what you done so far

Answer (score 1):

Implement a [`ContainerRequestFilter`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs-javax.jax-rs/2.0.1/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html)([more on filters](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)), which when a specific criteria is met will call:

```
ContainerRequestContext.abortWith(javax.ws.rs.core.Response)
```

with a proper HTTP status code.